# SQL Using row data from one table to choose data from a specific column in a different table

Tags: sql, sql-server, calculated-columns

I have one table with row data that matches column names in a different table as such:

```
Items:  
ProdName    ProdNum  Quality  Type   Price
Teddy Bear   123      Low      Toy    5
Airplane     234      High     Toy    20
Monopoly     345      Mid      Game   15
Chess        456      High     Game   20
```

```
Tax Bracket:
Type  Low  Mid  High
Toy   .05  .07  .1
Game  .06  .09  .11
```

And I want to add a column to the Items table with the Total_Price which is priceX(1+tax) based on type of item and the tier of item to get this as a final table

```
ProdName .... Price Total_Price
Teddy Bear    5     5.25
Airplane      20    22
Monopoly      15    16.35
Chess         20    22.2
```

How would I do this?

## Update

I made a mistake, the latter table was discount not tax, either way this is my code, but i am getting a syntax error on the SELECT clause:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Net_Price_Calc(@quality nvarchar(50), @type nvarchar(50), @Price DECIMAL)
Returns Decimal
AS
    Select case when @quality= 'Low' then (1-t.low)*price
              when @quality= 'Mid' then (1-t.mid)*price
              when @quality = 'High' then (1-t.high)*price
              end
from tax t
Where type = t.type
     ;
     Alter table Items
     Add Net_Price as dbo.Net_Price_Calc(Quality, Type, Price)
     ;
```

Error: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Net_Price_Calc, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Select'.

Comment: Use a `Case` statement to select appropriate Column for your calculation

Comment: Updated for with error to my latest code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `join` and a `case` statement:

```
select i.*,
       ((case when Quality = 'Low' then t.low
              when Quality = 'Mid' then t.mid
              when Quality = 'High' then t.high
         end) + 1) * Price as TotalPrice
from items i left join
     taxes t
     on i.type = t.type;
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to add a column to the Items table with the Total_Price

What you need here is a [Computed Column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx). However, you are drawing from multiple tables, so will need to define a function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Total_Price_Calc(NVARCHAR(50) @Quality, NVARCHAR(50) @Type, DECIMAL @Price)
RETURNS DECIMAL
AS 
   SELECT 
       CASE WHEN @Type = 'Low' 
       //Etc, see Gordon Linoffs reply
   FROM Tax
   WHERE Type = @Type
```

Then something like:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Items
   ADD Total_Price AS dbo.Total_Price_Calc(QualityValue, TypeValue, PriceValue)
```

Note that's just rough though, and not the quickest.

Or did you mean you wanted to create a query which computed a column at the end?

Comment: Your @Type in the CASE WHEN, should that be @Quality?

Comment: Yes correct, apologies.
Basically, because low/mid/high are the column names you need a case statement. Gordon Linoffs case statement below can be used, I just didn't duplicate it.

Comment: When I try to add the Alter Table line, I get a syntax error on ALTER